# wampserver src not outputting correctly

Tags: wampserver, src

im using wampserver on windows 7 and have wordpress set up. I am trying to include a js file using a couple of methods but the server is adding extra locations..

e.g. using wp_enqueue_scripts outputs:

```
wp_enqueue_script('qtip', AD_PATH.'/js/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
```

AD_PATH outputs correctly on screen when echo'd: `C:\wamp\www\market/wp-content/plugins/market`

but in the chrome console,  `http://localhost/marketC:wampwwwmarket/wp-content/plugins/market/js/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.js?ver=3.9.2` appears.

using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='localhost/market/wp-content/plugins/market/js/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.css'></script>
```

outputs

`http://localhost/market/merchant/register/localhost/market/wp-content/plugins/market/js/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.css`

this prepends the current page location to the src.

I had a problem with the wampserver index file not including localhost and changed $suppress_localhost to false and `$projectContents .= '<li><a href="'.($suppress_localhost ? 'http://localhost/' : '').$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';`

anyone any ideas?

Comment: WORDPRESS works much more reliably if you create a Virtual Host for it to run in. WP issues like this, was one of the main reasons that WAMPServer now actively encourages the creation of Virtual Hosts for all projects, however trivial, as questions like this one were taking up the majority of the WAMPServer forum. See this doc for [help creating Virtual Hosts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Comment: thanks very much for this, ill have a look at this later!

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem edit your `wamp/www/index.php` file. At line 30 there is:

```
$suppress_localhost = true;
```

Change it to:

```
$suppress_localhost = false;
```